# Django, Query filter by multiple time interval overlaps

Tags: django

I have a Worker and Task model.
The Worker has working hours (working_hours) and the Task has time to work (working_time).
These time fields are associated with the TimeInterval model as ManyToManyField. Each interval has a start and an end time.
I used a ManyToManyField because the Worker and Task can have multiple intervals for working hours.
For example, a worker can work in the intervals from 07:00 to 12:00 and from 15:00 to 18:00.
And the task must be completed from 13:00 to 17:00.

I need to make a query which tasks are suitable for a worker during working hours. Time intervals for work must overlap.
How can i do it?

I tried to get working time intervals from a specific worker, then in a loop form a condition for filtering using Q-objects.
Like this:

```py
my_worker = Worker.objects.get(id=1)
my_worker_working_hours = my_worker.working_hours.all()
time_conditions = []

for interval in my_worker_working_hours:
    time_conditions.append(
        Q(
            Q(working_time__start__lte=interval.end) &
            Q(working_time__end__gte=interval.start)
        )
    )

suitable_task = Task.objects.filter(*time_conditions)
```

This works if the Task has only one working_time interval. Otherwise, filter does not work correctly.

My models:

```py
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    working_hours = models.ManyToManyField(TimeInterval)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    working_time = models.ManyToManyField(TimeInterval)

class TimeInterval(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using SQLite.
I found there is PostgreSQL specific DateTimeRangeField in Django.
Does this solve my problem? I am not very familiar with PostgreSQL.

Comment: You want to find tasks that lie in interval1 OR interval2 OR ..., yes?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , Yes, at least one time interval must overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you use [or operator (pipe) with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
suitable_tasks = Task.objects.none()
for interval in my_worker_working_hours:
    suitable_tasks |= Task.objects.filter(
        Q(working_time__start__lte=interval.end) & 
        Q(working_time__end__gte=interval.start))
```